# Preventing the instantiation of a class via pure virtual functions?

Tags: c++, class, polymorphism, abstract-class

I'm looking at the following code in my book:

```
class Shape
{
    public:
        Shape(){}
        ~Shape(){}
        virtual long getArea() = 0; // Pure virtual function
        virtual long getPerim() = 0;
        virtual void draw() = 0;
};
```

Now it says that these virtual functions make the class abstract (which I understand from Java), so the class cannot be instantiated.

However, it says: *"a class is in abstract data type by including **one or more** virtual functions in the class declaration."*

Would this mean if I declared a class with **ONE** pure virtual function:

```
class Shape
{
    public:
        Shape(){}
        ~Shape(){}
        virtual long getArea() = 0; // Only pure virtual function
        virtual long getPerim(){}
        virtual void draw(){}
};
```

does the whole class become abstract? Because if a class has 100+ methods, it'll be tedious to write `=0` for every method if I decide to make it abstract later.

Comment: Think about what would happen if you could instantiate a class with only one pure function, and then try to call that...

Comment: If a class has 100+ methods, you have some design issues to address.

Comment: @juanchopanza Lol, yea, I was being hypothetical.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, a single pure `virtual` method is enough to make the class abstract.

Moreover, you can always make the destructor pure `virtual` if no other methods are suited to be pure.

Also, your destructor should probably be `virtual`, since you're obviously going to inherit from this class. This is mandatory if you plan on deleting objects of a derived type through a pointer to a base type.

Comment: I can still put methods within the non-pure functions, correct?

Comment: @Ken: Just to clarify a bit more, the class in your book has three pure virtual methods because it makes sense for each of them to be pure virtual. How to calculate the area, perimeter or how to draw a shape depends entirely on the specific shape, so these methods must be written by each derived class, hence they are pure virtual.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct in that one pure virtual method is enough to make the class abstract. That means you must implement the method in a derived class to instantiate an instance (of the derived class).

I have issues with your "class with 100+ methods". Usually this is a sign of very poor design.

I also have issues with your "tedious to write =0 for every method" attitude. Firstly I do not see why it is any more tedious to write =0 than it is to write {} as a default no-op implementation (and if the method returns anything, like `getPerim()` does, you risk undefined behaviour by not returning something). Primarily though, business logic dictates whether or not there is a default behaviour, and not the effort of writing.

Remember the Liskov substitution principle: Although one cannot have an instance of your base class, someone will have a pointer or reference to one, and call virtual methods on it without having to know what class they really have. (Incidentally Liskov was female, first name Barbara, and stated this principle sometime around 1983).

Your abstract base class should almost certainly have a virtual destructor, by the way.

Methods that will not change the state of the class should be declared const.

Answer (score 1):

Marking a function pure doesn't just make the class abstract, it makes any derived class that doesn't override the function also abstract.

So, if you want to force derived classes to implement all those functions, then make them all pure. If it makes sense for a derived class to implement only `getArea` and not the other two, then only mark `getArea` pure. In this example I suspect that it *doesn't* make sense, since if all the derived class has added is a way to compute the area, there's still no way that the base class can compute the perimeter.

Answer (score 0):

Declaring a method as pure virtual means that classes that inherit your class will have to implement that method or leave it pure virtual, in which case the derived class will also be an abstract class that cannot be instantiated.

Also, as Luchian said previously, you should always declare the destructor as virtual for every class that will be inherited.

Comment: _"you should always declare the destructor as virtual for every class that will be inherited."_ As read literally, this is bad advice. Luchian added a nuance indicating the purpose of this: to make `delete` via base pointer safe (not undefined behaviour). And that's the only case in which one "should always declare the destructor as virtual". For all other classes, where polymorphic deletion is not of interest, it should simply be prevented by making the destructor protected and non-virtual. This prevents the undefined deletion while, in contrast, not bloating every class with a virtual table.